Understanding QR decomposition in the context of a cubature Kalman filter
I am working on implementing a square-root cubature kalman filter based on the algorithm presented in this conference paper, as well as this paper more broadly.
I have got the algorithm to run; however, I want to make sure I am implementing it correctly before attempting to tune the results. From the conference paper, the sigma points for the KF are first generated:
$$\mathcal{X}^+_{k-1}=\hat{X}^+_{k-1}+\sqrt{n}\left[S^+_{k-1},-S^+_{k-1}\right]$$
Where $n$ is the number of states in the state vector. In my case $n=44$. To start the loop, $S^+=chol{Q}$, afterwards it is propogated through the filter recursively. After the sigma vectors are propogated through the prediction function $f$, I need to update $S$, and per the papers:
$$S^-_k = qr\left\{\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\left(\mathcal{X}^*_k-\hat{X}^-_k\right), S_{Q,k}\right]\right\}$$
This is where I am a little confused. Given there are $2n$ sigma vectors, each of $n=44$, then the matrix of propogated sigma points will be $44\ \text{x}\ 88$, assuming the vectors are column vectors. The papers are not clear what the notation of the bracketed term represents; typically this would indicate concatenation, which works ($S_{Q,k}$ is 44 x 44), but that would leave the argument for qr decomposition non-square. In Matlab I can use the \textit{qr} command to get the "roots", but this returns a square and non-square matrix. Can I just take the square one? That doesn't feel right.
There is another instance of this type of calculation later in the algorithm. The form is the same, but it is the matrix square root of the innovation covariance and uses $S_{R,k}$ (5 x 5) in place of $S_{Q,k}$ and uses the measurement sigma points which together are (5 x 88) for 5 measurements - this time to solve for $S_{y,k}$. Again, concatenation is possible along the column dimension, but then the next step is to solve the Kalman gain:
$$K = \left(P_{xy,k}/S^T_{y,k}\right)/S_{y,k}$$
Given this calculation, which works if $S_{y,k}$ is non-square, but only if oriented correctly, I went in thinking it would be square. I am also unsure as the authors never specified orientation for the state vectors (row or column), and I'm not sure how relevant that is to the mathematics.
I am also unsure of what shape $S^-_k$ should be. I assumed that all of the square roots are square matrices, but given that notation of the paper I don't immediately see a way to get it square. I am operating at the limits of my linear algebra understanding, so any insight is appreciated.
